# Best Way To Find a Username From a Facebook ID

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch

**I have a facebook user's id. How do I get their username?**

Specifically, I am using a FBFriendPickerController

```
for (id<FBGraphUser> user in self.friendPickerController.selection) {
   NSLog(@"The Facebook User: %@", user);
}
```

^This outputs stuff like the name, id, first name, last name, profile photo, but it does not give the user's username.

**So, in regards to FBFriendPickerController, what is the best way to get the username of a selected user?**

Comment: You can not (and you should not be able to) get username from FB API. You can gat user's name, last name, full name, middle name: but not the username (as part of the login credentials). If that would be possible it would be a security risk in FB API. That said, usually users e-mail (which you can get with FB API) is usually also ones login username.

Comment: @rokjarc I don't fully understand why it would be a security risk, look at my solution below, is there are a better way of doing this though?

Comment: If you can get ones username by (as part of the login credentials) his facebook id  this poses a security risk. All you need then is his password and you can hijack ones account. User's name (not username) is something completely different.

Comment: @rokjarc but the username is easily accessible using the solution below? #stillconfused

Comment: My bad: i was thinking about username one uses with his login. This is not the case with fb. For fb login you need to enter e-mail or phone (as login 'username').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something similar to this when setting up the friend picker controller:

```
// Initialize the friend picker
FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPickerController = 
    [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
...
// Ask for friend device data
friendPickerController.fieldsForRequest = 
    [NSSet setWithObjects:@"username", nil];
```

Then when the friend picker data is returned, the username info should be returned as well.

You can implement the friend picker delegate method for a roundabout way of getting the username info. Implement: friendPickerViewController:shouldIncludeUser:

In this method, you can examine the returned data that should include the username:

```
- (BOOL)friendPickerViewController:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker
             shouldIncludeUser:(id<FBGraphUserExtraFields>)user
{
    NSString *username = user.username;
    // Process the username however you wish to.
    return YES;
}
```

For a similar ask, in this case looking for "device" info see the doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/filter-devices-friend-selector-using-ios-sdk/

Comment: Thanks @CAbernathy that is a much better solution, LOL for a second I was like, I think I've seen you somewhere before, than I realized I saw you in the Facebook docs. Anyways, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured a way out.

You can find the username by looking at the JSON returned by

```
graph.facebook.com/(fb_id)
```

But is there a better way of doing this, straight from the friendPickerController, that is the question.